# auto submit form doesn't get submit if input field name value = submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to auto submit form using jquery. But the form doesn't get submitted because of `input name="submit"` value. I dont know why but if i change the name value to something other than submit it works. And this `name="submit"`is necesarry get the form submitted. So how can i auto submit this form using jquery or javascript ??

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="commant.php" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm" target="_myFrame">
    <textarea type="text" name="Comm">test submit</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</form>

<script>
$("form").submit(function(){
alert('Form is submitting....');
// Or Do Something...
return true;
});
$("form").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: `name="submit"` is not required for it to be submitted...

Comment: Why do you believe `name='submit'` is required? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input scroll to `name`

Comment: At least in the JSfiddle I was using I was having issues with the jquery form handler being attached before the DOM was fully loaded, so maybe try wrapping everything in a `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: I dont know. Its another website. I believe it is required because when i change submit value to any other name it simply doesn't submit. Its serverside i dont know how they use this.

Comment: Try `$("form:first").submit();`

Comment: @Amol doesn't works

Comment: Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ze305p9/)